# Read file as a buffer within an Expo application

Tags: react-native, jpeg, fs, expo

Specific problem is that the [Expo filesystem](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem.html) can only read a file as a string, but my desired usage (more below) is to read the file as a buffer. I'm hunting around the alternative filesystem libraries, but I'm not finding a clear solution.

At this level, my question is just simply: In an Expo app (so, react native), how can I read a file as a buffer?

The larger context is that I'm trying to do some photo processing with the JSFeat library. This library expects `Uint8ClampedArray` objects, which can be created from JPG files by the [JPEG-JS](https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs) library, and the Expo camera library automatically saves the photo to a JPG file.

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer to this problem ? I am having the same issue

Comment: So sorry, I don't think I did.